# Is there an approach to have feh --thumbnails do not display filename?

Tags: imagemagick, thumbnails, feh

I have many pictures which are screen shots created from shutter and downloaded from web. These pictures have long file names. When I create thumbnails on these pictures via `feh -t`, these long file name will prevent `feh` to display many pictures in one row.

And I did not find a solution for this on the `feh` man page. What can
I do to display many pictures in a row?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question and I know know the rules about that on this site but I found a solution (workaround maybe?) for myself just now:

Use `--font` to specify a truetype font that exists on your system and specify a size of `0`, eg:

```
feh --recursive --thumbnail --font "/usr/share/fts/truetype/openoffice/opens___.ttf/0" /mnt/pictures
```

Comment: This is the only workaround I could find, thank you! To take it a step further, you can use a font that maps to non-marking characters. This one worked for me: https://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Adobe+Blank/

Answer (score 2):

[firmgently’s solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/300015/178088) (setting the font size to 0) didn't work for me.

My solution is: setting the index-info flag to an empty string `--index-info ''`
-> removes the filename in the collage.

In this case:

```
feh --recursive --thumbnail --index-info ''  \
                            --font "/usr/share/fts/truetype/openoffice/opens___.ttf/0"  \
                            /mnt/pictures
```